# Two same forms works different in jQuery

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Hi I have 2 select drop down forms.

```
= f.grouped_collection_select :skill_of_objects, SkillSphere.where(name: any_skill_types(school_skill.skill_emphasis)).order(:name), :skills, :name, :id, :name_pl, {}, { class: 'add_skill_form close_me'}

= f.grouped_collection_select :skill_of_objects, SkillSphere.order(:name), :skills, :name, :id, :name_pl, {}, { class: 'add_skill_form'}
```

And an coffeescript action attached to them:

```
$(document).on 'change', '.add_skill_form', ->
  multi_skill = ['Wiedza','Rzemiosło','Artysta','Pokaz']
  skill_name = $('#character_skill_of_objects option:selected').text().replace(/ /g,"_")
  if $(this).hasClass('close_me')
    close_status = 'true'
  else
    close_status = 'false'
  if $(document).find('#skill_' + skill_name).length == 0 or skill_name in multi_skill
    $.ajax
      url: 'on_add_skill'
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        skill_id: $('#character_skill_of_objects option:selected').val(),
        close_me: close_status
      }
  else
    alert 'Skill exist'
```

The funny thing is, that the form that is upper in the dom works as expected, and the second allways return "skill exist", except for situation when it is used as first, and it works only once, after that if allways returns "skill exist" alert.

I wil be glad for any hint what is wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I was refering to the id of one element. So both forms, where using the same selected field. The solution was using 'this', for selected field.

```
$(document).on 'change', '.add_skill_form', ->
  multi_skill = ['Wiedza','Rzemiosło','Artysta','Pokaz']
  skill_name = $('option:selected',this).text().replace(/ /g,"_")
  if $(this).hasClass('close_me')
      close_status = 'true'
    else
      close_status = 'false'
    $.ajax
          url: 'on_add_skill'
          type: 'GET'
          dataType: 'script'
          data: {
            skill_id: $('option:selected',this).val(),
            close_me: close_status
          }
```